# How can I install mods in the Steam version of Torchlight 2?

Tags: torchlight-2

How can I install mods on the Steam version of Torchlight 2? Also, will any mod I install flag my account as "cheater" as the "respec potion" mod does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Torchlight II\PAKS` is where you put the mod files. Whether or not your account would be flagged depends on the mod. Most won't flag your character.

Comment: Of course, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam" depends on your actual Steam install location.

Comment: So all i have to do is create the PAKS folder in this path and drop the mods file there ?

Could you please add to your answer, which is the file format of those mods ? ( .what ? )

Comment: Actually, this answer is wrong. Because mod files are  to be put into a special folder My Documents.